# Facebook API - Search for mentions of page/brand (2016)?

Tags: facebook, api

Is this still not possible as of today? I couldn't find a corresponding API method. As there are social media monitoring platforms out there offering this feature, I guess it has to be possible somehow? Am i missing something?

There are similar quesions but they're over a year old which is why I wanted to start a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

facebook.graph.api/{pageid}/insights/page_stories?access_token={accesstoken}

That's in 2.8, you can see more references [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/insights/).

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah Facebook Graph is a bit tricky with their lingo. You get used to it after a while, :).